# Fetch first two rows of a group

Tags: sql, db2, grouping, rows

```
Item BatchNo
A    00001
A    00002
A    00003
B    00007
B    00008
B    00009
B    00010
```

I have a table as above and I wanted the result to give me the first two batch no. for each item. I'm using DB2 as400 by the way.

Eg:

```
Item BatchNo
A    00001
A    00002
B    00007
B    00008
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using

Comment: What AS/400 version, please?  Although all recent versions support the necessary functions.  This is a simple [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, all the standard answers should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Window Function` to fetch first two rows from each `item`

```
Select item, batchno from (
select item, batchno,row_number()over(partition by item order by batchno) Rn 
from yourtable) a
where rn<=2
```

Comment: Can this be supported on DB2?

Comment: @user3543512 Yes it is supported

Comment: Message: [SQL0104] Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: FROM INTO. Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token ,.  Token , is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is FROM INTO.  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the

Comment: @user3543512 - Are you sure that you got this error by running the above query without adding anything in the code

Comment: Yes. I didn't alter anything

Comment: You need `select a.*, row_number() ...`  DB2 for the i doesn't allow an unqualified * unless it is by itself.

Comment: @user3543512 - as charles mentioned that might be the problem. Updated my answer check now

Answer (score 0):

Here are some variations ASAIK these work (inbetween gigs no testing)

*STRAIGHT UP QUERY*

```
select item,batchno from yourfile 
where row_number()over(partition by item order by item,batchno) <=2
order by item,batchno
```

*COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION QUERY*

```
with cte  as (
select item, batchno,row_number() over(partition by item order by item, batchno) rn 
from yourtable)
select item,batchno from cte where rn<=2 order by item,batchno
```